# Identifying the reversal records which are created more than one time for an Actual record

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using an custom interface to load some records into base tables for a project. In this interface I need to create a reversal record for an actual record with the subsequent month(Period). Because of some reason the reversal record got duplicated and I could see that multiple reversal records got loaded for one actual record.
Now I want to identify the reversal records which has got created more than one time for an actual record.

Ex:- my table data looks like below

```
ID    Project   Emp No  Period  Hours    
--    -------   ------  ------  -----
 1     P1         E1    201810   10
 2     P1         E1    201811  -10
 3     P1         E1    201811  -10
 4     P1         E1    201811  -10
```

Now I need a SQL query to identify the reversal records which occurred more than one time(in this case ID's 3,4).

The query output need look like below

```
ID    Project   Emp No  Period  Hours    
--    -------   ------  ------  -----
 3     P1         E1    201811  -10
 4     P1         E1    201811  -10
```

Can anyone please help me to get this done..

Answer (score 1):

Is this sufficient?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (partition by Project, EmpNo, Period, Hours order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the rows that do not contain the minimum `id` of each distinct group of `Project, EmpNo, Period, Hours`:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tablename t
WHERE t.ID <> (
  SELECT MIN(tablename.ID) 
  FROM tablename 
  WHERE 
    tablename.Project = t.Project 
    AND 
    tablename.EmpNo = t.EmpNo 
    AND 
    tablename.Period = t.Period 
    AND 
    tablename.Hours = t.Hours
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`grouping by` with `having` clause as in the following case displays the desired result

```
with tab( ID, Project, EmpNo, Period, Hours ) as
    (
     select 1,'P1','E1',201810, 10 from dual union all
     select 2,'P1','E1',201811,-10 from dual union all
     select 3,'P1','E1',201811,-10 from dual union all
     select 4,'P1','E1',201811,-10 from dual
    )  
select *
  from tab
 where ID > 
  ( select min(ID)
      from tab
    group by Project, EmpNo, Period, Hours
    having count(*) > 1
     );

    ID  PROJECT EMPNO   PERIOD  HOURS
    --  ------- ------  ------  -----
    3   P1      E1      201811   -10
    4   P1      E1      201811   -10
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/MRID67615)

Answer (score 0):

This can be broken down into three views: (1)the actual transactions (2)the multiple reversals and (3) reversal details

```
select dtl.* from 
  (select * from base_table where hours > 0) act,
  (select proj, emp, period, count(*), min(id) min_id 
   from base_table where hours < 0
   group by proj, emp, period having count(*) > 1) multi,
  (select * from base_table where hours < 0 ) dtl
where 
/* join actual transaction with multiple reversals.  NOTE: period clause below won't really handle year-month math */
act.emp = multi.emp
and act.proj = multi.proj
and to_number(act.period) + 1 = to_number(multi.period) 
/* find details of redundant reversals  */
and multi.min_id != dtl.id
and multi.emp = dtl.emp
and multi.proj = dtl.proj
and multi.period = dtl.period
```

Maybe not the most efficient solution, but should work (except it needs code to handle 201812 actual that are reversed in 201901)

Answer (score 0):

with order and rownum in subquery

```
select dt.ID,
       dt.Project,
       dt.Emp_No,
       dt.Period,
       dt.Hours from (    
select * from my_table order by Period desc) dt
where rownum <= 2
```